# Illiterate, the use of the word in speech

Tags: prepositions

Can I say the following sentence:

"She is/I am illiterate in/at something"?

Comment: Do you know the literal meaning of _illiterate_? It doesn't mean 'not very good at...'

Comment: Thank you a lot, I am more interested in the usage, namely: can I use any preposition after "illiterate"

Comment: @OlgaKozelskaya Since illiterate means *unable to read or write* you cannot be "unable to read or write in /at / [any preposition]"

Comment: Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

**Illiterate** means *unable to read or write*, so it isn't a good choice of word when you seem to be wanting to say "I am not at all good at [some task]". The choice of preposition is therefore irrelevant. If someone can barely read they are *almost illiterate* - you don't need to add *at reading.*

You can say "I am hopeless at mathematics" or "I find mathematics very difficult", for example.

Comment: I am really grateful, I see I was confusing this word with something else, or maybe I thought it slided to a wider meaning)) thank you

Comment: Actually, you _can_ stretch the meaning to 'knowing almost nothing about a subject', but it's normally used with an adverb - 'musically illiterate' rather than 'illiterate in/at music'.